# Decide if $((((P\wedge Q)\wedge R)\wedge S)\wedge T)\Rightarrow(\neg P\vee T)$ is a tautology

Tags: propositional-calculus

How can I show that $((((P\wedge Q)\wedge R)\wedge S)\wedge T)\Rightarrow(\neg P\vee T)$ is a tautology?

I tried to apply the implication rule $(p\Rightarrow q)\equiv (\neg p\vee q)$ but it doesn't seem to bring me anywhere.

Comment: Have you done a truth table?

Comment: $((((P∧Q)∧R)∧S)∧T)≡P∧Q∧R∧S∧T$

Comment: Can you show the truth table for the left side.

Comment: @Inazuma Yes, I can do that. I just thought I could apply some formulas to simplify it.

Comment: @stillenat Nevermind, G. Sassatelli has already provided a valid explanation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}\text{your expression}&\equiv \neg ((\text{stuff})\wedge T)\vee(\neg P\vee T)\\\color{blue}{[\text{De Morgan}+\text{associativity}]}&\equiv\neg(\text{stuff})\vee\neg T\vee\neg P\vee T\\\color{blue}{[\text{commutativity}+\text{associativity}]}&\equiv(\neg T\vee T)\vee (\text{whatever})\end{align}

The last is a tautology.

Answer (score 1):

You have (conjunction ⇒ disjunction). T is present in the conjunction and the disjunction. Your implication is a tautology.

Formal proof (e.g., sequent calculus):

Start from (T ⇒ T)

Dilute the antecedent (by adding conjuncts) and the consequent (by adding disjuncts)